# VSCode Autocomplete Displaying 'abc' Instead of Keywords

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm using VSCode and currently facing an issue where autocomplete isn't working properly. It simply shows everything as 'abc' instead of recognizing keywords such as 'elif' or 'else'. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you install python extensions ?

Comment: That's the expected behavior if you are in a string or comment.

Comment: I have installed all the required extensions and I’m not in a string or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try to reinstall VSCode and Python extension.
2. You can also check whether you have chosen the correct python interpreter by shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose it.
3. You can add `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` to your `settings.json`
   4.Perhaps you've disabled "semantic token color customizations". You can add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": false
},
```